# React - How to Set a checkbox from props using array destructring

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, destructuring

There is a React MUI Datagrid with list of users and when a user row is clicked, another dialog window opens with individual details of an user. I use props to send the value from DataGrid to Dialog.

There are 2 checkbox fields (to see if user has Android or Ios device sign in rights which is loaded from backend) described as below

```
    // Component
    const UserDialogData = (props) =>{
    
     const [platform, setPlatform] = useState({
        Android: false,
        Ios: false,
      });
    
    
      const { Android, Ios } = platform;
    
     useEffect(() => {    

        
          // How to set the props.IsAndroid and props.isIos to be set sothat variables 'Android' and 'Ios' are set to the checbox
        
       
      });


return(<>
 <FormGroup row>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Checkbox                     
                  size="small"
                  checked={Android}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  name="Android"
                />
              }
              label="Android"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Checkbox                     
                  size="small"
                  checked={Ios}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  name="Ios"
                />
              }
              label="iOS"
            />
          </FormGroup>
</>);

}
```

Now I want to set the useEffect to set the boolean value to the setPlatform. Can anyone please help.

I am new to React and not able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried and somehow found the answer by myself. I leave this post so that anyone who struggles like me can utilise it.

```
 const UserDialogData = (props) =>{
    
     const [platform, setPlatform] = useState({
        Android: false,
        Ios: false,
      });
    
    
      const { Android, Ios } = platform;

     

   useEffect(() => {
   
      setPlatform({
        ...platform,
        Android: props.isAndroid,
        Ios: props.isIos,
      });
    
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need useEffect here. Just set the props values in two different boolean states and use them accordingly. Try like this:

```
const UserDialogData = (props) => {
 const [isAndroid, setIsAndroid] = useState(props.isAndroid);
 const [isIos, setIsIos] = useState(props.isIos);

 return (
  <>
   <FormGroup row>
    <FormControlLabel
     control={
      <Checkbox
       size="small"
       checked={isAndroid}
       onChange={() => {
        setIsAndroid(!isAndroid)
       }}
       name="Android"
      />
     }
     label="Android"
    />
    <FormControlLabel
     control={
      <Checkbox
       size="small"
       checked={isIos}
       onChange={() => {
        setIsIos(!isIos)
       }}
       name="Ios"
      />
     }
     label="iOS"
    />
   </FormGroup>
  </>
 );
};
```

Comment: Yes. But the code is completed by another team like this. I have to talk a lot to convince why this could be presented like your answer. I have to find possiblity of how to do it first. Only if I cannot do it, I can change the way like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to make a small edit to your answer it's better to get the oldPlatformData from the state
so instead of this

```
   useEffect(() => {
      setPlatform({
        ...platform,
        Android: props.isAndroid,
        Ios: props.isIos,
      }); 
  });
```

use this

```
   useEffect(() => {
      setPlatform((prevSate) =>({
        ...prevSate,
        Android: props.isAndroid,
        Ios: props.isIos,
      }))
     });
```

Comment: Sure. I will see if this way fulfills my required action and utilize it